# Use a listbox selection to select and go to a cell

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/513mu.png)I have a workbook that contains a different worksheet for each industry sector in the S&P 500 i.e Tech, Energy, Ect. and I created a userform with two listboxes that allow the user to first select a sector then a sub sector that is unique to that sector. The listboxes are working just fine, but now I want to create a command button that takes whatever sub sector the user selects and makes the first row of data on the active sheet containing that sub sector the active cell.

```
Private Sub GoToSectorButton_Click()
'Declare variables
Dim SubIndustry As String
Dim IntRow As Integer

'Set list box value equal to the variable
SubIndustry = lstSubIndustry.Value

'Locate the first occurance of the Sub Industry
IntRow = 3

'Select the row that contains
ActiveSheet.cell(SubIndustry).Select

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'declare variable
Dim shtIndustry As Worksheet
'shows Industries in lstIndustry that aren't the first set of sets
For Each shtIndustry In Application.Workbooks("VBA_Finance_Project_KEZE6983.xlsm").Worksheets
    If shtIndustry.Name <> "Welcome" And shtIndustry.Name <> "Name Or Sector" And shtIndustry.Name <> "Name" And shtIndustry.Name <> "Sector" And shtIndustry.Name <> "Filter" And shtIndustry.Name <> "Master" Then

        lstIndustry.AddItem (shtIndustry.Name)

    End If
Next shtIndustry

'select default list box item
lstIndustry.ListIndex = 0

End Sub

Private Sub lstIndustry_Click()

'declare variables
Dim strSI As String, rngData As Range, rngCell As Range, shtSubIndustry As Worksheet

'clear list box
lstSubIndustry.Clear

'Save relevant worksheets to a vaiable so that we can use the vaiable in the rest of the program as a shortcut
Set shtSubIndustry = Application.Workbooks("VBA_Finance_Project_KEZE6983.xlsm").Worksheets(lstIndustry.ListIndex + 5)

'activate worksheet clicked
shtSubIndustry.Activate

'assign address of Industry data to rngData variable
Set rngData = Application.Workbooks("VBA_Finance_Project_KEZE6983.xlsm").ActiveSheet.Range("A3").CurrentRegion

'assign Column heading to srtSI variable
strSI = "GICS Sub Industry"

'Add the Sub Industry
For Each rngCell In rngData.Columns(14).Cells
    If rngCell.Value <> strSI And rngCell.Value <> "" Then
        lstSubIndustry.AddItem rngCell.Value
        strSI = rngCell.Value
    End If
Next rngCell

'select default list box item
lstSubIndustry.ListIndex = 0


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate through the rows that contain the subIndustry value. If the subIndustry names are in column 'A'.

Something like (warning: untested)

```
Dim c as Range
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For Each c In Range("A1:A" + LastRow).Cells
  If c.Value == subIndustry Then
    c.parent.activate 'Activate worksheet
    c.select
    Exit
  End If
Next
```

Comment: That didn't work it is saying Invalid or unqualified reference. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Eric K edited the code in my answer, may work now. If you want further help you'll have to be more specific. What line are you getting the error in? What is it highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

Below function I use for my joining logic, it help identify the Row Number for matched record.

This Function is flexible can match multiple criteria.

In your case,

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = getRowMultiMatch(Array(Range("M:M"), Range("N:N")), 1, Array(Sector,Subsector))


Function getRowMultiMatch(ByVal arrRange As Variant, ByVal startMatchOnRow As Single, ByVal arrMatchValue As Variant) As Single
'Return 0 if unable to match
'arrRange = Array of Source Range
'startMatchOnRow = 1
'arrMatchValue = Array of Value need to Match

Dim i, nRow, nStartRow, nLastRow As Single
Dim nRng, dataRng, nColRng As Range
Dim nWSD As Worksheet
Dim nValue As Variant

        Set nColRng = arrRange(0)
        Set nWSD = nColRng.Parent

        'Start and Last (Row Number) Help define when to stop looping
        nStartRow = nColRng.Cells(1).Row
        If startMatchOnRow > nStartRow Then nStartRow = startMatchOnRow
        nLastRow = nColRng.Cells(nColRng.Cells.Count).Row

Retry:
        'Sizing nRng
        Set nRng = Intersect(nColRng.EntireColumn, nWSD.Range(nWSD.Rows(nStartRow), nWSD.Rows(nLastRow)))

        nValue = arrMatchValue(0)
        If IsNumeric(nValue) = False Then
            nValue = CStr(nValue)
            nValue = Replace(nValue, "*", "~*")
        End If

        'Matching First Item
        If IsError(Application.Match(nValue, nRng, 0)) Then
            getRowMultiMatch = 0
            Exit Function
        Else
            nRow = Application.Match(nValue, nRng, 0)
            'Looping to Check if all values are match
            For i = 1 To UBound(arrMatchValue) 'Start loop from 2nd Item
                Set dataRng = Intersect(nWSD.Rows(nStartRow + nRow - 1), arrRange(i).EntireColumn)
                If StrComp(dataRng.Value, arrMatchValue(i)) <> 0 Then
                    'Not Match
                    'Resize nRng then Retry
                    GoTo NotMatch
                Else
                    'Matched
                End If
            Next i
            'All Matched
            getRowMultiMatch = nStartRow + nRow - 1
            Exit Function
NotMatch:
            nStartRow = nStartRow + nRow
            If nStartRow > nLastRow Then
                Exit Function
            Else
                GoTo Retry
            End If
        End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks this helps, but it still isn't doing exactly what I am looking for it to do. I want the selected cell to be the SubIndustry that the user selects. The userform currently has two listboxes one that includes all the sectors and when the user clicks on a sector it goes to that sheet then the second listbox is populated with the unique sub industry values related to that sector. So I then want the unique sub industry that the user clicks on in the listbox to be the selected cell on that sheet.

Comment: Maybe u can snapshot your sub sector list. Do you means Autofilter by subsector in the Sector worksheet ?

Comment: How do I add a screenshot of it on here?

Comment: It is in my description now

Comment: To confirm, do you means when click go to sector, it will Autofilter your data, Column M & N, whichever records meet Sector & SubSector ?

Comment: I just need it to make the active cell the first cell in column N that contains the selected item in the subindustry listbox

Comment: you can use ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = RowYouWantToGo, in your case need a lookup logic to find out the Row Number.